# Float matrix left among other matrices

Tags: floats, align, matrices

I'd like to float one matrix left among the others, and make the text grey. Currently, I can only simulate this by adding the correct `\hspace*{}` after my first matrix that I would like to align left.
My current code looks like such,

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
 \begin{document}    
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{matrix}
  \ket{11}\\
  \ket{01}\\
  \ket{10}\\
  \ket{00}
\end{matrix} \hspace*{50pt}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  1\\
  0
\end{pmatrix} 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and yields the following
[image: example image]

Concluding; how do I left align/float the first matrix and make the text grey?

Comment: I suggest you to add those three or four lines to make the Minimal Example also Working, i.e. a MWE. If you make so, you'll help us to help you!

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What exactly should I add?

Comment: I mean `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, needed packages... I could do it for you, but doing it by yourself will make you a better user! ;)

Comment: and used packages for this equations as well `\begin{document}` and `end{document}` ...

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Updated!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That'll be my mistake. Fixed now!

Comment: @Isaiah, I gave you a simple answer about the color, but I did not understand what you'd like to obtain in terms of alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `flalign` environment and `{\color{gray} ket matrix }` (requires `color` or `xcolor`. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` since `mathtools` does it:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{xcolor} %
 \usepackage{mathtools}%
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{flalign}
  &{\color{gray} \begin{matrix}
  \ket{11}\\
  \ket{01}\\
  \ket{10}\\
  \ket{00}
\end{matrix}} %
& \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  1\\
  0
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
  & =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0
\end{pmatrix}
 & & %
 \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, maybe you could mention this requires the `xcolor` package?

Comment: I'll add it. But isn't it obvious any colour specification require requires a dedicated package – color or xcolor?

Comment: Well, one (new user) could think that one of these commands is in some automatically loaded package of the class or something similar...

Answer (score 2):

The `xcolor` package's `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` command could simply help you with the color. The `{\color{<color>} text}`, is another option, but I like the former more.